# Binding text to <option> does not work in an ng-switch-when block in IE8

Tags: angularjs

Binding to an `<option>` in a `<select>` box does not work in IE8 if the `<select>` box is in an `ng-switch-when` block of a `ngSwitch` directive.  This issue is consistent for both double bracket binding and `ng-bind`.

The exact same markup outside of an `ng-switch-when` will result in the binding being correctly resolved.  This is even the case if the `select` is outside of an `ng-switch-when` but still wrapped by the `ng-switch`.

In other browsers the `<option>` correctly binds whether the `<select>` is in or out of  `ng-switch-when`.  I tested in Chrome 29 and Firefox 23 and 9.

I created a jsbin demonstrating this behavior: http://jsbin.com/oqeNUdU/2/ .

In IE8 the drop down will contain `{{'Some bound text'}}` in other browsers simply (and correctly) `Some bound text`.

I believe this to be an Angular bug and as such I've filed an issue against the GitHub repository, in the mean time I am looking for a work around that will properly render the following code across browsers.

```
<div ng-switch on="foo()">
  <div ng-switch-when="someCase">
    <select>
      <option>
        {{'Some bound text'}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
<!-- other cases -->
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't init the option value in a controller via scope and then get this value like  {{myvalue}}. Create a controller and should be fine i think

Comment: I'm binding a string literal in my example because it's the simplest example I could concoct, but binding variables set through the controller suffers from the same problem in an `option` nested in an  `ng-switch-when` in IE8.

Comment: It strange because this issue has been close in angular ...

Comment: look : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/235

Comment: What's most frustrating is that if you use developer tools and inspect the DOM the text node is correctly 'Some bound text'.  I don't know why this isn't being reflected in the browser.

Comment: Have you try a ng-cloak property on the div with ng-switch ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The contents of the option tag was not displayed correctly in IE8 when it was inside an ng-switch directive.
I solved this by using the ng-options directive (in Angular 1.2.3).